# How to get Spring REST to lead all endpoints with /v1/ after the domain and port?

Tags: spring

How do I make a Spring REST service assign a value after the domain and port, but before the mapped endpoint? For example: `http://{domain}/v1/...`?

Example:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("home")
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("number")
    public ResponseEntity getNumber() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(1);
    }
}
```

`curl http://localhost:8080/v1/home/number` ~ `1`

Also, is there a name for what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: on the class, you want `@RequestMapping("v1/home")`

Comment: You should look for 'context path' keywords, because that's the name of the thing after domain.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Spring Data Rest, you can configure it in the `RepositoryRestConfiguration` `@Configuration` class like so:

```
public class SDRConfig extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {
    @Override
    public RepositoryRestConfiguration config() {
        RepositoryRestConfiguration config = super.config();
        config.setBasePath("/v1");
        return config;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, with Spring Boot I believe it's

```
spring.data.rest.baseUri=api
```